# How to clear out all the finished Future results of @Async tasks with Spring-Boot?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, asynchronous

I have trouble understanding the usage of `@Async` annotation and methods since I am quite inexperienced in the multithreading field.

I have some `Map<Integer, String> map` and I want to update this `map` using the asynchronous method calls. This method makes `HTTP GET` request on a page with `int id` which returns `String string` as result - it is updated to the `map` and I need to get the updated result value:

```
@Async
public Future<Entry<Integer, String>> updateEntry(Integer key, String value) {
    Entry<Integer, String> entry = // Method call updates String value (let's say HTTP GET request takes few seconds)
    return new AsyncResult<Entry<Integer, String>>(entry);
}
```

Since this method won't work if called using `this`, there is another class executing those methods:

```
private final Map<Integer, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

private void update() {

    // KICK THE ASYNC METHODS UP
    List<Future<Entry<Integer, String>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    map.forEach((key, value) -> {
        futures.add(asyncObject.updateEntry(value));
    }); 

    // FETCH THE RESULTS
    Iterator<Future<Entry<Integer, String>>> iterator = futures.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Future<Entry<Integer, String>> future = iterator.next();
        if (future.isDone()) {
            try {
                Entry<Integer, String> entry = future.get();
                this.map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                iterator.remove();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                // SH*T HAPPENS, LOG IT
            }
        }
        if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
            iterator = futures.iterator();
        }
    }
}
```

I have stored all the future results in `futures` and the result sooner or later will appear. I think a good way is to use endless `while-loop` to check if [`Future::isDone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isDone--), the iteration above is briefly described below:

1. Iterate the `futures` list endlessly (0, 1, 2 .. 8, 9, 10, 0, 1, 2...) using [endless Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016605/how-can-i-make-an-iterator-that-never-ends).
2. If `Future<Entry<Integer, String>>` is done:

   - Update the map using `Map::put` which replaces the entry
   - Remove `Future<Entry<Integer, String>>` from the `List`
3. Stop the endless iteration if the list `futures` is empty.

This solution surprisingly (my first multithreading experiment) works.

Is this solution thread safe and of a correct approach? Is the usage of `ConcurrentHashMap` sufficient? I have no idea how to test unless printing the actions to the console or log. What might happen if the `map` would be updated by another `@Async` call at the moment of `update` method call - would be making this method `synchronized` sufficent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me approach looks good. Nothing should happen if map updated during `update` method run since `ConcurrentHashMap` is used. If you want prevent simultaneous `update` run you can make method `synchronized` or use some lock. You can take a look on `CompletableFuture` and `allOf` it will manage futures for you and emit new one when all futures done.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Are you sure that the ConcurrentHashMap is sufficent for this use case? Anyway, have my +1 and let me be honored to move you among 10k guys ;))

Comment: Just a note, I don’t want to wait for all the Futures becaus eone might finish immediatelly while another in a minute. I want a continuous update.